# Laravel update localization files on deploy

Tags: laravel, deployment, localization

I have dev and prod servers. Localization files are stored in the code on the git, but on the production server through the admin panel, these files can be changed.
How correctly update localisation files, when deploying to the production server?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store them at the same place that the code is stored, or at least don't deploy them when code is deployed to prod. Add some post-deployment script that checks which localisation files are missing from prod and only ever download those ones and keep the rest intact.

Comment: Alternatively, i can store translations in a database, and after deploy add missing keys to database. But what about performance? What is faster, pull texts from files or databases.

Comment: This is not a question of files, because I can add only one key to a file. In this case, the file will be overwritten, but I need to merge the files exactly.